# how to create while loop in select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns

[image]

I want to output query like

[image]

I try to use loop in SQL but I failed to output query

My question is: how can I repeat the values in the [Name] column by the number in the [Total] column?

Comment: *If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly* - please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/12511801).

Comment: Well, you can't use loops in plain SQL. This is available in Procedural SQL. What you need can be achieved using for example recursive query with some calculation.

Comment: ok how ???.......

Comment: how are you getting the initial sql result (the table that shows accumulated total)

Comment: ok i need I want to execute the statement more than once, according to the existing number in column [total]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually handled with a recursive subquery. I derived a row order in case of duplicate names, however, that is best served using a unique key.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3986f/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Names(name NVARCHAR(50), total INT)
INSERT Names VALUES('ahmed',3),('mahmoud',2),('ahmed',5)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH Normalized AS
(
    SELECT *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) FROM Names
)
,ReplicateAmount AS
 (
    SELECT  name, running_total=total, total, RowNumber
    FROM Normalized

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.name, running_total=(R.running_total - 1), R.total , R.RowNumber
    FROM ReplicateAmount R INNER JOIN Normalized N ON R.RowNumber = N.RowNumber
    WHERE R.running_total > 1
)   

SELECT 
    name,instance=RowNumber,total=1,OriginalTotal=total,running_total 
FROM 
    ReplicateAmount
ORDER BY
    RowNumber,name,total,running_total
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3986f/2/0)**:

```
|    name | instance | total | OriginalTotal | running_total |
|---------|----------|-------|---------------|---------------|
|   ahmed |        1 |     1 |             3 |             1 |
|   ahmed |        1 |     1 |             3 |             2 |
|   ahmed |        1 |     1 |             3 |             3 |
| mahmoud |        2 |     1 |             2 |             1 |
| mahmoud |        2 |     1 |             2 |             2 |
|   ahmed |        3 |     1 |             5 |             1 |
|   ahmed |        3 |     1 |             5 |             2 |
|   ahmed |        3 |     1 |             5 |             3 |
|   ahmed |        3 |     1 |             5 |             4 |
|   ahmed |        3 |     1 |             5 |             5 |
```

Comment: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: max 100 row >>>>>>>>

Comment: Add  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) After the query. There is a limit of 32767 recursive frames.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this considerably simpler than the accepted answer.

I would suggest creating a numbers table with sequential positive integers...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM sys.all_objects o1, 
     sys.all_objects o2
```

and then just join on `number <= total` (as below)

```
SELECT name, 1 AS total
FROM Names nam 
JOIN dbo.Numbers num ON num.Number <= nam.total;
```

If you are on 2017+ another method for "fun" is below ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c37b/1))

```
SELECT name, 1 AS total
FROM Names
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SPACE(total - 1), ' ')
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: Many of our production systems are pre SQL 2016. This does make queries less verbose, however.

Comment: @MahmoudMagdyMousaa - Will add the code for the Numbers table example then

Answer (score 0):

For your closed question;

```
CREATE TABLE #Test1(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Cnt] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE #Test2(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE #Test3(
    [ID1] [int] NULL,
    Cnt int,
    Id2 int,
    [col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ID, Cnt) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ID, Cnt) VALUES (2, 3)
INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ID, Cnt) VALUES (3, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ID, Cnt) VALUES (4, 2)
INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ID, Cnt) VALUES (5, 1)
INSERT INTO #TEST1 (ID, Cnt) VALUES (6, 4)


INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1')
INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2')
INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (3, 'a3', 'b3', 'c3')
INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (4, 'a4', 'b4', 'c4')
INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (5, 'a5', 'b5', 'c5')
INSERT INTO #TEST2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (6, 'a6', 'b6', 'c6')

declare @a int = 1, @b int, @c int = 0;
while @a <= (select MAX(Id) from #Test1)
begin
    set @b = (select Cnt from #Test1 where ID = @a);
    set @c = 0;
    while @c < @b begin
        insert into #Test3 (ID1, Cnt, Id2, col1, col2, col3) select @a, @b, @a, col1, col2, col3 from #Test2 where ID = @a;

        set @c += 1;
    end
    
    SET @a += 1;
end

select * from #Test3 order by 1, 2;
```

[image]